# Backup configuration for Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, backup, webserver, snapshot

How can I make a restore point for a Ubuntu Server 18.04?

I have a clean install of the Ubuntu Server OS and before installing any Web Server I want to perform a backup and if something goes wrong with the installation I want to backup/ return to that point that I have created just before. Another case would be if I have installed let's say Apache2 and is working correctly and then I want to install in the same machine Apache Tomcat and something goes wrong how can I roll back to the stable version, what is the best practice.

So far I have been using `rsync` trying to back the root `/` but it always leads to some problems. Also, I have seen that snapshot is usually to save a specific folder and not a server configuration.

With the backup, I want to achieve that not to reinstall OS from the beginning every time and to perform a clean installation of everything.

Comment: If your server runs on a virtual machine you can store a snapshot of the VM's disk and roll back. If you install the OS with Btrfs (on hardware) you also have a snapshot tool (`snapper`) which enables you to roll back easily to a previous snapshot of your system. If you need a solution for an already installed system (non-btrfs) you should look out for suitable backup tools. Maybe someone else has other recommendations here.

Comment: @eblock I am hosting a VPS online, and it has a 130GB HDD with LVM. So I can not do much and before deploying something I want to make sure that the web servers are working correctly.

Comment: You can create LVM snapshots, does [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm_snapshots) help?

Comment: For quick rollbacks, LVM Snapshots or Virtual Machine Snapshots(Xen, VMware) are your best options here. To make a reliable "system backup" you will have to know all aspects of your software(Distro Version, Packages installed, customized configuration files, users, special permissions, security tweaks) and that isn't something we at the bigger community can provide you...